# jQuery .html( data here ) seems to "re-size" the response text

Tags: jquery, response, font-size

Consider the following code.

It's an anchor tag with an id called **leader-module-total** that - when pressed - calls a PHP script and displays the echos done in the PHP code inside an id called **leader-module**.

Basic enough.

However, each time I do this, I need to "shrink" it using the last piece of code in this snippet.

My question is, how come? Am I doing something wrong here?

```
$('#leader-module-total').click(function() {

   //load an image to show while processing
   $('#leader-module').html( '<div class="ajaxLoader"></div>' );

   //process the php script -- btw, is this valid i.e. calling it using / 
   //and not fully qualified with http://mydomain/page-to-be-called  
   $.get('/ajax-leader-module-response.php', { timeframe: 'total' }, 
       function(data){
          $('#leader-module').html( data );
       }
   );

   //this is my question: why is this necessary???  
   //I need to make it smaller than it was for it to display normally.
   $('#leader-module').css('font-size', '0.9333em');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Maybe the HTML you're injecting in does not have one or more of the CSS classes that is should have?

Comment: See the answer below.
Since my parent tag had a font-size: 1.3em i.e. the EM in the font-size makes it relate to what it was and so when it refreshed the content of the tag it also made it 1.3em from that original 1.3em it had from the parent tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is inheriting styles from the parent tag. Please check the parent elements for any font size style.

Comment: Yes. It did.
I didn't know jQuery .html() re-executed the parent tag when replacing the data in it. At least that's how it comes out in all major browsers.

Thanks a lot for the help.